# The Projection Matrix Does More than Scaling, Right?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, projection-matrix

As I have it understood, a projection matrix scales a polygon depending on how far away or close it is from the camera. Though I might be completely wrong. **My question is, how does the projection matrix "know" to show the sides of the following [cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg3kB.png), as the camera moves, when the matrix is only supposed "scale" polygons?**

Notice in the image, the cube is off to the right side of the screen, by moving the camera to the left. If the camera is moved in the opposite direction (to the right) in order to center the cube, the side of the cube will disappear as expected.

Here is my matrix code:

```
private void createProjectionMatrix(){
      float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();         
      float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV/2f))) * aspectRatio);         
      float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;         
      float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;                  
      projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f(); 
      projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;         
      projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;         
      projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);         
      projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;         
      projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);         
      projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function of a projection matrix (in the context of graphics APIs, such as OpenGL) is to transform vertex positions from view-space into clip-space.

Clip space is generally a unit box (although in D3D it's a half-unit box). If a vertex position after being transformed into clip-space does not lie within that unit box, then it is clipped. This is essentially how the system "knows" the cube is visible on the screen.

Comment: although this answers that the cube is still visible on the screen, it doesn't answer how it updates the cubes position when the camera moves. Perhaps you can explain further or provide visual details?

Comment: I don't have your program, so providing visuals is pretty much impossible... 'Camera' movement is generally handled by the view matrix, not the projection matrix. Usually there are three matrices that determine how an object ends up in clip-space: the model matrix (orientation and position of the object 'in-the-world'), the view matrix (orientation, position of the 'camera'), and the projection matrx (how the camera's view is projected). If the view changes, this would result in a change in the cube's position within clip space - if the change is large enough, it could be outside the clip-box.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But even after disabling every other matrix, the sides of the above triangle are still being rendered correctly. I just want to know the "how" of the projection matrix for showing/hiding the sides of the cube.

Comment: Download the last `7z`from [here](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads). Inside you will find a pdf, it is one of the best resource to learn about opengl and transformations